# Embedding tables of data into a DocuSign template

Tags: docusignapi

I've got a form (in an ASP.NET application) that a person will add multiple rows to that represent items they are wishing to purchase. These items I want to display on a DocuSign document for them to sign.

Since there could be 1 item, or there could be 100, I'm not quite sure how to embed a field in the DocuSign template that I can populate with this data, they all seem to be for a single item when you use the DocuSign API to set a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kim's solution is a good one. Another solution is for your app to dynamically create the document itself.

For example, there are many libraries available that enable your app to create a PDF. Your app would then upload the PDF to DocuSign and programmatically create the fields (tabs) that you want.

Instead of PDF, your app can create an HTML, RTF or other type of document that will then be automatically converted to PDF by DocuSign.

Answer (score 1):

With DocuSign, the field values you specify are overlayed onto the (static) document(s) that you specify. In other words, there's no DocuSign functionality that would automatically scale the size of a table (number of rows) based on the number of rows of data you specify.

However, if you know the range of possible row counts that your table could possibly contain, you could still achieve the end result that you're seeking. For example, let's say you know your table will always contain between 1 and 10 rows. You could create 10 separate documents -- the first one with a 1-row table, the second with a 2-row table, the third with a 3-row table, etc. Then, at runtime, when you know how many rows of data the table will contain, use the API to add the appropriate document to the Envelope (or, if you've created a Template in DocuSign for each of the 10 documents, specify the appropriate Template for the Envelope). Obviously this approach doesn't scale well, and makes document maintenance a challenge (since if you need to make a change to the underlying document at any point in the future, you'll need to do that change to *N* documents) -- but it's the only way to solve for the scenario that you've described.

Note:  If your possible range for number of rows is a large number (like **100**, for example) -- you don't necessarily have to create 100 documents, as long as you're okay with tables containing empty rows. For example, if there could be a maximum of 100 rows, you could just create 10 documents -- the first one with a 10-row table, the second with a 20-row table, and so on. Then at runtime, if there are less than 10 items for the table, you'd use document #1; if there are between 11-20 items, you'd use document #2, etc. Using this example, your table could end up containing up to 9 empty rows (for example, if there are 11 items, you'd add them to a table that contains 20 rows, leaving the final 9 rows of the table empty). This obviously isn't ideal, but would likely be preferable (from an initial effort standpoint, and a doc maintenance standpoint) to creating 100 different documents.